# "New additions *for*..." or "New additions *to*..."

Tags: prepositions, to-for

If I'm trying to advertise that you can scroll through this webpage to find additions that go in/on your home, would it be...

> "Find new additions **for** your home."

> "Find new additions **to** your home."

Does "find **for** your home" *technically* mean that your home itself is literally looking for new additions and you're looking on its behalf? And therefore "**to**" is correct?

The problem is, what if it were something like advertising gift-giving, and said...

> "Find shoes **for** your friend."

In that case, it could be read as finding shoes *on behalf of* your friend, but also finding shoes *that suit* your friend. Certainly, "find shoes **to** your friend" is absurd. So, why does it work in the home example (assuming "**to**" is correct in the home one)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does "find for your home" technically mean that your home itself is literally looking for new additions and you're looking on its behalf?

In the UK, homes are not sentient beings, nor do they possess organs capable of finding things...

You will note that

"Find" is (i) an imperative with an implied subject of "You" or (ii) an infinitive with an implied modal "can/may/will, etc" and a subject of "You"

**for** = for the benefit of

**to** = associated contextually with

Comment: *for* here could easily mean "for use in" rather than "for the benefit of" (that is, there is more than one expansion available).

Comment: @AndrewLeach "for noun" may create what is sometimes referred to as a "beneficial dative" (there are other terms available) - hence "benefit".  I baked her a cake - I baked a cake for her.

Comment: And again, "I baked a cake for her" could mean "I baked a cake **on her behalf** [because her oven was broken]." To say *for* is exclusively "beneficial" isn't right, and it almost certainly doesn't apply to the OP's "for your home". The home doesn't benefit; those who use it do.

Comment: The home does benefit. This is not the restricted use of "benefit". If you do something "on her behalf" - she benefits... We are arguing which end the egg should be opened...

Answer (score 0):

For this native speaker of American English, and in the context you provide,

> Find new additions **for** your home

conveys potential: “Here are some things you could do…” (I don’t read the sense of “on behalf of” that concerns you.) It is the far better choice. By contrast, using the preposition *to* establishes a sense of completion. And

> Find new additions **to** your home

has the peculiar effect (again, *for me*) of changing the meaning of *find* (!). It  might be suitable in a context like

> During your six months abroad, our builders have been very busy preparing a surprise for you. When you get home, you will find [that they have made] new additions to your home.”

As for why *to* is syntactically acceptable, that’s because addition is something we idiomatically do **to** houses, while we don’t find shoes **to** friends.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers are consistent of my understanding. I will just make it a touch clearer.  An addition **to** your home would be a feature that becomes part of the whole that is your home. A fence, a swimming pool or a deck. An addition **for** your home might be suitable for your office or home such as hat stand or a hall mirror. I've upvoted Greybeard's answer.